# DataTables warning: table id=users_list - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I am getting  data from users table based on active-inactive status after that with foreach loop data should be displayed using data table but getting an error

> DataTables warning: table id=users_list - Invalid JSON response

so my requirement is

```
1) Show all data in the data table
2) per page 5 records
3) Default search box of a data table
4) Pagination of a data table
```

Following is my code  but this didn't work for me
In index.php file dropdown list and based on onchange event ajax call to a users_list method in ajax controller.

```
In index.php  file drop-down list with ajax call request



 <select class="custom-select" onchange="get_users(this.value)">
        <option value="active">Active</option>
        <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
    </select>
<div class="show_data"></div>

    <script>
    function get_users(status){
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'<?php echo SITE_URL . 'ajax/users_list'; ?>',
    data:{ status:status},        
    success: function(data)
    {        
    $(".show_data").html(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
    alert('Failed');
    }
    });
    }

    </script>
```

In controller Ajax.php

```
function users_list(){
$status=$this->input->post('status');   //active  or inactive 
$data['users']=$this->db->where('status',$status)->get('users')->result();
$this->load->view('view_assets',$data); 
}
```

In view_assets.php files

```
<table id="display_userinfo">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-light">
            <th>user id</th>
            <th>user name</th>
            <th>Mobile no</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $user->id ?></td>
                <td><?= $user->name ?></td>
                <td><?= $user->mobile ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    <script>
        $('#display_userinfo').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript**

You've set [`ServerSide`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) to be true when you invoke `DataTable()`. But you've already created the table. Change this:

```
    $('#display_userinfo').DataTable({
        "processing": true, //Optional, only useful for *large* tables
        //"serverSide": true, //REMOVE THIS
    });
```

From their documentation:

*By default DataTables operates in client-side processing mode, but can be switched to server-side processing mode using this option. Server-side processing is useful when working with large data sets (typically >50'000 records) as it means a database engine can be used to perform the sorting etc calculations - operations that modern database engines are highly optimised for, allowing use of DataTables with massive data sets (millions of rows).*

You should only use [`ServerSide`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) if you're planning on feeding `DataTable()` JSON. Otherwise you can just run `DataTable()` without the [`ServerSide`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) flag and it will translate your HTML to its format.

If you rejig your backend you can still use [`ServerSide`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide), but it may not be necessary. Here's an example to get your started:

```
$('#display_userinfo').dataTable( {
  "serverSide": true, //Here it's necessary
  "ajax": {
     "url": '<?php echo SITE_URL . 'ajax/users_list'; ?>',
     "data": {}
   }
});
```

**HTML**

You've also made a small markup error, that may or may not have an impact on DataTables. Change the following:

```
    <tbody> <!-- This needs to be BEFORE the foreach() loop -->
<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= (int)$user->id ?></td>
                <td><?= htmlspecialchars((string)$user->name) ?></td>
                <td><?= htmlspecialchars((string)$user->mobile) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody> <!-- Correctly placed *AFTER* the foreach() loop -->
```